# Pass local element reference in method call from template

Tags: angular, reference, this, dry, self

In my template, I want to be able to do the following:

```html
<div somedirective="myvalueA" directiveABC="myvalueA" directiveXYZ="myvalueA"></div>

<span somedirective="valB" directiveABC="valB" directiveXYZ="valB"></span>

<input somedirective="blaC" directiveABC="blaC" directiveXYZ="blaC"> </input>
```

As you can see, the value of somedirective is repeated in the other directives. I'd like to write it like this:

```html
<!-- does NOT work -->
<div somedirective="myvalueA" directiveABC="this.somedirective" directiveXYZ="this.somedirective"></div>
```

Is there some way to obtain a reference to the current element?

**Note:** 
I **do not** want to create a local variable for every element (no #myDiv, #mySpan, ...)!

**Edit**: I have no control over the directives - they are part of a library. The directives could also be normal attributes, this question just attempts to avoid breaking the DRY principle.

Comment: Just use the same `@Input` in `directiveABC` and `directiveXYZ` or inject `someDirective` in others

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `valB`, `blaC` and `myvalueA` are expressions rather than variables?

Comment: They are just regular strings. My goal is to just define the string "myvalueA" one time (e.g. somedirective="myvalueA") and then reuse this value on other directives (or attributes).